# Show that Language L = { <M> | M is a TM and {b}* ∩ L(M) ≠ ∅ } is recursively enumerable?

Tags: formal-languages, turing-machines, proof-techniques, recursively-enumerable

I'm not sure how to show that the language L = {M | M is a TM and {b}* ∩ L(M) ≠ ∅ } is recursively enumerable. I understand that if there is a DTM that accepts every word of the given alphabet, it is recursively enumerable. But I dont know how to properly show this, can anyone help?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I didnt really try anything yet, since I dont know how to show recursive enumerability...

Comment: How about you read some material about this topic before trying to solve an exercise you don't understand?